# Magento SQLSTATE[42S01] error

Tags: mysql, magento

I've been having problems with my magento site.  It suddenly crashed, and locked me out from even entering admin.  I contacted our host to roll back our DB and nothing has changed.  I even deleted the tables with the errors as suggested and cleared my local cache and /var/cache/ and still nothing.  I have hundreds of products in the DB and don't want to flush them out, how can I fix this?

> Error in file:
>   "/home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_assert' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE admin_assert (
>   assert_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Assert ID' ,
>   assert_type varchar(20) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Assert Type' ,
>   assert_data text NULL COMMENT 'Assert Data' , PRIMARY KEY (assert_id)
>   ) COMMENT='Admin Assert Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8
>   COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
>
> Trace:
>   0 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
>
> 1 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '',
>   '1.6.1.1')
>
> 2 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.1.1')
>
> 3 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
>
> 4 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
>
> 5 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>
> 6 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 7 /home/sppower6/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 8 {main}

Comment: It's difficult to see how this is really a programming problem. You might do better asking on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

just delete the `admin_assert`

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_assert' already exists
```

if still happen, you can refresh your domain `yourdomain/index.php` it until it done.

Because when `index.php` it will check **all core_resource version at db**, when it's not same or lower from `config.xml`, it will **run mysql upgrade**.